# select menu not working in ios 8

Tags: cordova, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I have created a phonegap application using javascript and html in which the **select menu** is not working in ios 8. But it is working well in ios 7. I dont know how to solve it.any help please?

```
<select name="country_id" style="margin:0 !important;" tabindex="1" id="sel_country">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Us">Us</option>
            <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into my project and it works fine for me with cordova 3.6.3. Have you updated your cordova/phonegap?

Comment: is it working in ios 8?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have many webview with options and the options are not working. I just get a view with this buttons "< > OK". But this happens only in iPhone 6 simulator. In iPhone 5s simulator it works ok.

Comment: ya in 5s it is working but i want it to work in 6 also. Any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the select menu working in the iOS 8 simulator by going to Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the ios-sim 8.XX. On a device running 8.XX the select element does work as expected. Hopefully there will be an update to the ios-sim to fix this in the near future.

Discussed Here:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-issues/201409.mbox/%3CJIRA.12744525.1411872889000.141139.1411885533954@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, this is a SIMULATOR ONLY bug.

You can get the choices to show up by pressing <kbd>⌘K</kbd> when the blank chooser shows up at the bottom of the screen.